# Stop conversion of content between pre tags in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, redcarpet

Running a small site off Jekyll. One problem that I keep running into is that the markdown keeps modifying content that is between *pre* tags.

Two conspicuous examples.

First:

```
<pre>a & b</pre>
```

gets converted to

```
<pre>a &amp;</pre>
```

Second example:

```
<pre>I am "happy"</pre>
```

converts to

```
<pre>I am “happy”</pre>
```

If it isn't that clear, the latter example is converting the quotes to smart quotes. This  is bad for me because my pre tags contain code examples where smart quotes become syntax errors. Also, I've tried using & between pre-tags, hoping the converter would instead insert an &. Instead, it (sigh) leaves it as &

Is there an obvious way to tell Jekyll (or Redcarpet) that a section of the code should not be run through the markdown converter?

Bradley

Answer (score 0):

Redcarpet 2.2.2 [does not modify code between HTML tags](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#also-now-our-pants-are-much-smarter). Try this in the [IRB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell):

```rb
require 'redcarpet'
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true, :fenced_code_blocks => true)
markdown.render("<pre>They're not for sale, says Johnson & Johnson.</pre>")
```

This was my result:

```rb
"<pre>They're not for sale, says Johnson & Johnson.</pre>\n"
```